# Which is the best metaphor or gesture for a radio button (YES/NO) on touch screen interface?

Tags: tablet, gestures

I need to design a radio button for selecting/deselecting items using gestures. 
The app is on Surface tablet. Users can select/deselect a vehicle they are intersted in.

I would like to go beyond the usual radio button or check box.

Please if you have any suggestions share links and ideas with me.

Edit:
Client explicitly asked for something connected to the world of agriculture. The website is selling agricultural machines. I am ok with keeping it with a simple tap gesture but I was looking for something connected with agriculture.

Each item is quite big, it covers something like 2/3 of the screen.

Comment: how big is each item? *Touch* to keep & *Pinch* to discard?

Comment: What is wrong with press to select? It's the ideal metaphor - "I want this one" and you touch it. Any gestures (swiping, circling etc) are just superfluous.

Comment: Client explicitly asked for seomthing connected to the world of agriculture. The website is selling agricultural machines. I am ok with keeping it with a simple tap gesture but I was looking for something connected with that world

Comment: each item is quite big, it covers something like 2/3 of the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Client explicitly asked for something connected to the world of agriculture"*

Perhaps you could argue the following simple metaphors:

**Touch to keep**. To touch is akin to identifying with something, to form a bond, or to nurture or care for something. By using the word touch you are suggesting the user wants to keep the item. It's also the simplest gesture to either select or access a list of actions.

**Swipe to move on**. This is like parting a wheat crop or field of grass as you walk through it. You want to make forward progress without damaging or marking the crop so you part it with your hands as you walk on (being careful where you tread). Swiping to progress is also a common gesture, eg mobile 'switch on' states where you swipe a picture or a button to access the applications, or to switch articles like in FlipBoard, or in a timeline of some kind.

**Pinch to discard**. This is like the '[pinching out](http://www.thompson-morgan.com/how-to-grow-sweet-peas)' of plants where you remove small shoots by pinching between finger and thumb to train the plant. Similarly, by pinching to remove an item on the screen, you train your selections by pinching out the ones you don't want.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If it's truly an on/off or yes/no choice, then a **toggle switch**  is generally preferred. Android, iOS and Windows 8 all have them:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It should of course be clear what the "on" and "off" states mean, and by default the "active" state generally involves adding a color (and for whatever reason, moving to the right). I'd recommend sticking to default controls where possible as these are recognizable controls. If you're going to roll your own switch like this, remember to make sure the drag gesture works on it; the Android and iOS ones can be dragged (I assume Win 8's can be as well).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the highlight around the image to indicate that the image is the one that is selected?